# How to solve this problem using if-else loop in java selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

If variable value between j =<10 then page through error "Sorry ! user already..."
and then I try to assign another random value to variable k and fill up form again.

I want to execute `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'Sorry ! ')]")).isDisplayed()` step only if I get error. Else just print success message.

Problem here is even if I get success message I'm getting element not found error due to `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'Sorry ! ')]")).isDisplayed()`.
I also tried implementing `boolean Sorry_Error = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'Sorry ! ')]")).isDisplayed();` but I think it is similar logic just different way of implementation. if there is no error then loop should go for else block but insted it searching `.isDisplayed` xpath and throwing error.
Isn't it correct way to handle user already exist error or is there any other logic.

[This is success message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j2xVx.jpg)

[This is error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Qf9U.jpg)

```html
package com.self.learn;

import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class testandquiz {

    public static WebDriverWait wait;

    @Test
    public void Simple_Test() throws InterruptedException {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.silentOutput", "true");
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "src/main/resources/chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
        driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();

        driver.get("https://www.testandquiz.com/user-registration");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("scroll(0,300)");

        WebElement Fname = driver.findElement(By.id("first_name"));
        WebElement Lname = driver.findElement(By.id("last_name"));
        WebElement User_name = driver.findElement(By.id("user_name"));
        WebElement email_address = driver.findElement(By.id("email_address"));
        WebElement password = driver.findElement(By.id("password"));
        WebElement re_password = driver.findElement(By.id("re_password"));
        WebElement city = driver.findElement(By.id("city"));
        WebElement state = driver.findElement(By.id("state"));
        WebElement country = driver.findElement(By.id("country"));
        WebElement pin_code = driver.findElement(By.id("pin_code"));
        WebElement contact_no = driver.findElement(By.id("contact_no"));

        Random randomGenerator = new Random();
        int j = 10;
        int k = 99999;
        int i = randomGenerator.nextInt(j);

        Fname.sendKeys("Test" + i + "");
        Lname.sendKeys("Test" + i + "");
        User_name.sendKeys("Test" + i + "");
        email_address.sendKeys("Test" + i + "");
        password.sendKeys("Test" + i + "");
        re_password.sendKeys("Test" + i + "");
        city.sendKeys("Test" + i + "");
        state.sendKeys("Test" + i + "");
        country.sendKeys("Test" + i + "");
        pin_code.sendKeys("Test" + i + "");
        contact_no.sendKeys("1234567890");

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(text(),'Sign Up')]")).click();

        if (driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'Sorry ! ')]")).isDisplayed()) {

            WebElement Fname1 = driver.findElement(By.id("first_name"));
            WebElement Lname1 = driver.findElement(By.id("last_name"));
            WebElement User_name1 = driver.findElement(By.id("user_name"));
            WebElement email_address1 = driver.findElement(By.id("email_address"));
            WebElement password1 = driver.findElement(By.id("password"));
            WebElement re_password1 = driver.findElement(By.id("re_password"));
            WebElement city1 = driver.findElement(By.id("city"));
            WebElement state1 = driver.findElement(By.id("state"));
            WebElement country1 = driver.findElement(By.id("country"));
            WebElement pin_code1 = driver.findElement(By.id("pin_code"));
            WebElement contact_no1 = driver.findElement(By.id("contact_no"));

            Fname1.clear();
            Fname1.sendKeys("Test" + k + "");
            Lname1.clear();
            Lname1.sendKeys("Test" + k + "");
            User_name1.clear();
            User_name1.sendKeys("Test" + k + "");
            email_address1.clear();
            email_address1.sendKeys("Test" + k + "");
            password1.clear();
            password1.sendKeys("Test" + k + "");
            re_password1.clear();
            re_password1.sendKeys("Test" + k + "");
            city1.clear();
            city1.sendKeys("Test" + k + "");
            state1.clear();
            state1.sendKeys("Test" + k + "");
            country1.clear();
            country1.sendKeys("Test" + k + "");
            pin_code1.clear();
            pin_code1.sendKeys("Test" + k + "");
            contact_no1.clear();
            contact_no1.sendKeys("1234567890");

            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(text(),'Sign Up')]")).click();
        }

        else {

            String Message = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(text(),'verification mail')]")).getText();
            System.out.println(Message);
        }

    }
}
```

I don't know how to implement this logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't necessarily need a wait here... depends on if javascript updates the DOM.  If it's after a standard page load, then just use:

```
   List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Sorry')]");
        if (elements.size() > 0)
            {
            // sorry found
            }
            else
            {
            // sorry not found
            }
```

Else use try/catch with a wait:

```
 try {
         WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5);
         WebElement element =  wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Sorry')]"));     
            // sorry found             
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
         //sorry not found
         }
```

Use same logic for error text.

Comment: When I use `WebElement Error = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Sorry')]");`  it gives **element not found error.**
but `List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Sorry')]");` works for me.
if possible can you specify reason.
@pcalkins

Comment: findElements() returns an array.  So if nothing is found it returns a 0 length array instead of throwing an exception.